# path variable in Environmental variable accepts only one path

Tags: path, environment-variables

There is a path to JDK in Environmental variable and I'd like to add another path for spark. But whenever I click on the path variable to edit it, it only lets me change the existing path and does not let me add another path to it. Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Path editor dialog window]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. Simply add the second path you would like to add after the existing path and separate them with ";". This way, both paths are added and in case you want add more paths, by clicking on "edit" you can simply create a new path within the "path" variable.